# Exponential series expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

I feel like an idiot having to ask but I am honestly stuck and can't find the solution in my old text books.

We know that the Taylor series expansion of the exponential function is given by $ e^z = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}$. Similarly it follows that $ ze^z = \sum_{k=0}^{inf}k\frac{z^k}{k!}$.

I know that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^k\frac{z^k}{k!}=e^{ez}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{kr}\frac{z^k}{k!}=e^{e^rz}$, but honestly don't know how to get there. I am assuming that you have to take the log of the exponential of the function, but can't seem to get it right.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If $c$ is any complex number, then replacing $z$ with $cz$ yields
$$ e^{cz}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c^k\frac{z^k}{k!}$$
Taking $c=e$ or $c=e^r$ leads to the formulas in your question.

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you very much!